# Interpreting $\{x~|~x\in\Bbb N_1~\land~x\leq50~\land~(\forall y~(y\in\{2,\dots,x/2\})\implies(x\not\equiv0\pmod y))\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am learning universal quantifiers and existential quantifiers and I am still at the beginner level. I found a question in my lecture slides as following

$$\left\{\;x~|~x\in\Bbb N_1~\land~x\leq50~\land~(\;\forall y~[(y\in \{2,\dots,x/2\})\implies(x\not\equiv0\pmod y)]\;)\;\right\}$$

and the answer was given as

$$\{1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47\}$$

$\Bbb N_1$ means NAT1 which means natural numbers which are starting from $1$ ($1$ inclusive).

Unfortunately, I don't understand how does that answer come. So any help with a step by step explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick *MathJax* tutorial so that you can write mathematical formulas properly ;) What exactly does **xx, yy** refer to; why the double letters? Also, what exactly is **N1** and **xx mod yy 6**? Please clarify these details with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3495754/edit).

Comment: @mrtaurho thanks for the comment. Yah my bad i haven't described it much. Now I did an edit, just me let me know for further clarifications

Comment: Thank you, for your clarifications. The modulo part stills looks odd, or at least uncommon. Do you mean $x\not\equiv0\mod y$?

Comment: @mrtaurho modulo parts means x mod y ≠ 0.

Comment: I've edited your post by including *MathJax*. Please review if everything looks correct.

Comment: Nope, @mrtaurho. What I want to get actually is when you divide x from y there should be a remainder. Like  x= 3 and y = 2 then 3/2 the remainder is gonna be 1.5 such that the result is not equal to 0. I am not actually sure whether your expression does that? Just give me an example how does it work?

Comment: Well, $3\equiv1\not\equiv0\mod2$, as $3$ divided by $2$ gives a remainder of $1$. As far as I can tell this is the intended meaning, as the set described are precisely the primes $\leq50$ and $x\not\equiv0\mod y$ roughly translates to $x$ is not divisble by $y$ without remainder. Note, $x\equiv0\mod y\iff x=a\cdot y$ where $a\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yah thats the exact behavior I wanted. Sorry in my previous comment the remainder should be 1. So any step by step explanation of how this whole expression works?. However thanks @mrtaurho, I learned a new thing today from you.

Comment: The logical negation of $\forall y\in \Bbb N_1\;(A\implies B)$ is $\exists y\in \Bbb N_1\;(\neg (A\implies B)),$ which is equivalent to $\exists y\in \Bbb N_1\;(A\land \neg B)$.... With $A$ being $2\le y\le x/2$ and with  $(\neg B)$ being $x\equiv 0 \pmod y,$ this means that if $50\ge x\in \Bbb N_1$ then $x$ does NOT belong to  your set if and only if $x$ is divisible by some $y$ with $2\le y\le x/2,$ that is, if and only if $x$ is composite.... BTW on this site the custom is that $\Bbb N$ denotes the positive integers. I don't like it but I conform to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us decompose the whole expression step by step. First, we have our intial declaration of what type of things we are even looking for to collect in our set

> $$\{x~|~x\in\Bbb N_1\}=\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}\tag1$$

So we are looking for natural numbers $x$(starting by $1$). But they have to met some other conditions too, denoted by conjunction $\land$. Second, we have a restriction concerning their size

> $$\{x~|~x\in\Bbb N_1~\land~x\leq50\}=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,49,50\}\tag2$$

Now, a new variable comes into play: $y$. In contrast to $x$ its not clearly mentioned that we also have $y\in\Bbb N_1$ as all of our $y$ are defined to belong to the list $2,3,\dots,x/2-1,x/2$, or to put it in a slightly different way: we have $y\in\{2,3,\dots,x/2-1,x/2\}$. We demand that for *every* $y\in\{2,3,\dots,x/2-1,x/2\}$ it holds that $x\not\equiv0\mod y$ *simultaneously*. This is encoded by the formula

> $$\forall y((y\in\{2,3,\dots,x/2-1,x/2\})\implies(x\not\equiv0\mod y))\tag3$$

The role $\forall y$ plays here is to ensure the aforementioned simultaneity. Translating this into more familiar notions: we want to have that our number $x\in\Bbb N_1$ which is not divisble by any of the preceding numbers up to $x/2$ (we exclude all $y$ such that $x/2\leq y\leq x$ as they trivially fulfill this condition); that are precisely the primes (and $1$)!

Now, take a look at our complete set description

> $$M=\{x~|~x\in\Bbb N_1~\land~x\leq50~\land~(\forall y~(y\in \{2,\dots,x/2\})\implies(x\not\equiv0\pmod y))\}$$

We conclude that by $(1)$ and $(2)$ that we are looking for natural numbers $x\leq50$ and by $(3)$ such that they are not divisble by any of the preceding numbers. These are precisely the primes $\leq50$ expanded by $1$. So our solution set is

> $$\therefore~M=\{1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47\}$$

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @HelloWorld Glad to help!